# Remove wp-admin from the URL

Tags: url-rewriting

Is there any way to remove `wp-admin` from the URL of a WordPress site?

So for example instead of `www.example.com/wp-admin` the URL would just be `www.example.com`?

Comment: How you will separate the visitor site from admin panel?

Comment: I don't need the visitor side, just the dashboard.  It is for a decoupled installation and the front end lives elsewhere

Comment: so you want to access dashboard from just `www.example.com`?

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: Why don't just redirect every call to example.com to example.com/wp-admin?

Comment: Will that mask the URL for the visitor?

Comment: No. The final url would be example.com/wp-admin. Although you can change wp-admin to admin ie

Comment: What web server are you using - Apache | Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin for rewrite wp-admin url https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/
[image]